# UIAlertView won't call its method objective c

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

Here is my code. I'm working on a BAC calculator app. I'm trying to add an alert that asks the user to confirm when they add a drink (indicating that they just consumed one standard drink). Upon confirmation I want it to increase BAC (which is a global float variable) and then update the label on the view controller that displays the user's BAC (self.BACNum.text).

The problem is that the UIAlert is not responding when the user presses OK. Please help!

```
- (IBAction)AddDrink:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *addDrinkAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm adding one standard drink." message:@"A standard drink is 12oz beer, 5oz wine, or a 1.5 oz shot of 80 proof liquor." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


[addDrinkAlert show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

        if ([gender isEqualToString:@"Male"]) {
            genderConst = 0.68;
        }
        else {
            genderConst = 0.55;
        }

        BAC += (2.84)/([weight floatValue]*genderConst);
        self.BACNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", BAC];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target:self selector:@selector(metabolize:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        return;
    }

    else {

        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: set the delegate as self;

Comment: Coding for which iOS Version?, if you are coding for iOS 8 then this will not work(may be you were testing in iOS 8 simulator). For iOS 8 use AlertViewController(i have faced the same problem as you).

Comment: See my answer for how to use UIAlertController

Answer (score 0):

```
delegate:nil
```

There is your problem. You should pass here an object which conforms to `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol and implements `-alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. It's `self` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate `delegate:self`

```
UIAlertView *addDrinkAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm adding one standard drink." message:@"A standard drink is 12oz beer, 5oz wine, or a 1.5 oz shot of 80 proof liquor." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


[addDrinkAlert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem, when i have compiled my code for iOS 8. After finding lot things i comes to know about that for iOS 8, we have to use AlertController, Apple have stopped giving support to UIAlertView from now. Thats why your alertViewDelegate method is not working.

Please try following code, this will work surely.

```
UIAlertController *alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Confirm adding one standard drink." message:@"A standard drink is 12oz beer, 5oz wine, or a 1.5 oz shot of 80 proof liquor." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                     {
                                         // code for OK Button click
                                     }];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```